# How to Join three tables properly

Tags: mysql, sql

The main table has 4 columns:

User Activity Table

```
userActivityId  userId  therapistId activityId
1                1           1        1
```

Each of these columns is a table and these values are all foreign keys.

Basically im trying to run a query that will join to the users table and pull their first and last name based off the user Id.Same thing with therapist - join to the therapist table, pull first + last name.And finally Join to the Activity table and pull the activity name and path from the activity Id

The other tables look like this:

```
User Table
userId  fName   lName


Therapist Table
therapistId therapistFirstName  therapistLastName


Activity Table
activityId  activityTitle   activityPath
```

So far my query looks like

```
SELECT 
User_Activities.userId, 
User_Activities.therapistId, 
User_Activities.activityId, 
Activities.activityTitle, 
Activities.activityPath, 
Users.fName, 
users.lName, 
Therapists.therapistFirstName, 
Therapists.therapistLastName 
FROM 
User_Activities 
INNER JOIN Users 
ON User_Activities.userId = Users.userId
INNER JOIN Therapists ON 
User_Activities.therapistId = Therapists.therapistId
INNER JOIN Activities ON
Activities.activityId = User_Activities.userActivityId
WHERE 
User_Activities.userId = 1;
```

When I run this query It only returns 1 row as a result. However there are two activities in the User_Activites table assigned to userId 1.

If I change : INNER JOIN Activities ON
    Activities.activityId = User_Activities.userActivityId

from an INNER JOIN to the LEFT JOIN it will display the second row, however the activityTitle and activityPath will be displayed as NULL in the second row.

```
userActivityId  userId  therapistId     activityId    activityId    activityTitle   activityPath    fName   lName   therapistFirstName  therapistLastName   
1                 1           1              1            1         Brain           GZZ0zpUQ         S        C            M                      D
11                1           1              1           NULL              NULL            NULL      S        C             M                        D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have pretty much answered your question.  The second activity does not have a valid `ActivityId`.

If you want *all* activities for a user, then you should phrase the query as:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM Users u LEFT JOIN
     User_Activities ua
     ON ua.userId = u.userId LEFT JOIN
     Therapists t
     ON ua.therapistId = t.therapistId LEFT JOIN
     Activities a
     ON a.activityId = ua.userActivityId
WHERE u.userId = 1;
```

You want to start with the table where you want to keep all the rows.  Then use `LEFT JOIN` to bring in other tables.

Two other changes of note:

- Table aliases are used to simplify reading and writing the query.  The `SELECT` needs to change to use the aliases.
- The `WHERE` clause refers to the `Users` table rather than `UserActivities`.

Comment: I added this code to the query:

FROM
    Users
LEFT JOIN User_Activities ON User_Activities.userId = Users.userId

LEFT JOIN Therapists ON User_Activities.therapistId = Therapists.therapistId

LEFT JOIN Activities ON Activities.activityId = User_Activities.userActivityId

WHERE
    Users.userId = 1


However the end result remain the same. Did I make an error when trying to implement your code?

Comment: I tried to format that into lines to mak eit easier to read, but it doesnt seem to allow proper formatting in the comment section.

Comment: @AndroidNewbee . . . The code looks right.  Based on your description, it should fix the problem.  Can you set up a db fiddle of some sort?

Comment: Not used that before, but tried to set up the tables. Heres the link:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cgRCrSi7hzfZvJCQncqNb4/2

Comment: got it working, just changed the last line from   ON a.activityId = ua.userActivityId   TO  ON a.activityId = ua.activityId